# Using SPEL to call a method in the same class passing a variable taken from the actual method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aspectj, spring-el

I want to be able to call another method of my class by passing the value of a parameter of the calling method, so suppose:

```
public class MyClass{

   @MySpelAnnotation("#this.otherMethod()") //how to I pass "arg" as parameter?
   public void mainMethod(String arg){
        ...
   }

   public void otherMethod(String arg){

   }
```

How can I be able to take arg from the first method and pass it to the second one?

Comment: Are you looking for an AOP based solution ? At which point of execution ( before , in between or after ) of the first method , the second method should be invoked ?

Comment: After the first one is executed